# How to drop records containing cell values equals to the header in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, header, drop

I have read in this dataframe (called `df`):

[image]

As you can see there is a record that contains the same values as the header (`ltv` and `age`).

How do I drop that record in pandas?

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ltv':[34.56, 50, 'ltv', 12.3], 'age':[45,56,'age',45]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with

```
out = df[~df.eq(df.columns).any(1)]
Out[203]: 
     ltv age
0  34.56  45
1     50  56
3   12.3  45
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to just filter it out (assuming the strings match the column name they are in):

```
out = df[df['ltv']!='ltv']
```

Another could be to use `to_numeric` + `dropna`:

```
out = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna()
```

Output:

```
     ltv age
0  34.56  45
1     50  56
3   12.3  45
```